# Is there a way to use "others" as index when assigning to slices of VHDL array?

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to do something like this in VHDL?

```
 a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 ...
 a(1 ,3, others) <= ('0','1','0');
```

Rather than what I do at present:

```
 a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 ...
 a <= (others=>'0');
 a(1) <= '0';
 a(3) <= '1';
```

Comment: If doing anything critical I usually prefer to make direct explicit assignments for all possibilities so there is no way the synthesizer could misinterpret what I intended.

Comment: @user_1818839 That should be posted as answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like, using an array aggregate :

```
a <= (1 => '0', 3 => '1', others => '0'); -- or simpler 
a <= (3 => '1', others => '0');
```

Comment: I did this and I get this error:

COMP96 ERROR COMP96_0597: "Aggregate with multiple choices has a non-static or null choice. Use -relax to compile aggregates composed of one non-static or null choice and choice others."

Comment: When you get an error message like that, it's always worth posting the toolchain and version. But as the message hints, if you want to do it this way, you'll need the -relax compile flag.

Comment: Note that ghdl, which is possibly one of the strictest VHDL compilers according to standards compliance, has no problem with this code (assuming `a` is declared in the same architecture and thus its length is static)

Comment: However, take care to only use this in an assignment as the rules for ordering may produce unexpected results in an expression.   OK, so using others in an expression is also a non-starter as the expression needs to be sized.

Comment: @JimLewis Indeed, the assignment target provides the size and direction here, whether or not there are static values or just 'others'.